# why the context is window when using the "this" keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about "this" in JS and I have the following code:

```
var person1 = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Snow",

  printName: function(){
    console.log(this);
  }
}

var person2 = {
  firstName: "Aria",
  lastName: "Stark",

  printName: function(callbackFunction){
    console.log(this);
    callbackFunction();
  }
}

person1.printName();
person2.printName(person1.printName);
```

The output of this code is:

person1

person2

window

I understand why to context is person1 and person2 accordingly but why when I call the callback the context is window and not person2?

Comment: Because the value of `this` is determined by how the function is called.. `callbackFunction` is called without any context hence global(`window`) is returned...

Comment: Hi Rayon,

What I don't understand is why no context? I called "printName" when person 2 was the context so why when I call the callbackFunction from within "printName" the context doesn't remain person2?

Comment: As I commented on answer – _"It matters how they are called, not how they are passed..."_ Refer ___[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)___

Comment: So is it right to say that when calling the callBackFunction the browser looks for it in the current context(person2 in this case) and after it doesn't find that function it looks for it higher in the hierarchy(window in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

`callbackFunction` in your case is an expression (of type function) which is taking the context based on how they are invoked (window's context if no context is provided).

If you want the person1's method to be called then tweak it as

```js
var person1 = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Snow",

  printName: function(){
    console.log(this);
  }
}

var person2 = {
  firstName: "Aria",
  lastName: "Stark",

  printName: function(context, callbackFunction){
    console.log(this);
    callbackFunction.bind(context).call(null);
  }
}

person1.printName();
person2.printName(person1,person1.printName);
```

Here I am passing the `context` also, in which the `callbackFunction` should be invoked.

And in the function `person2.printName` I am binding the context to the callback funciton.

Comment: Guru – _"taking the context of from where it is being passed"_ sounds wrong.. It matters how they are called, not how they are passed...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback seems perfect dupe to me.. Will flag if you agree...

Comment: @Rayon You are right about both comments